# odoo change default type of graph

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

Per odoo [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#graphs) if you want to change the default type of graph you add the xml tag type and set it to the desired type such as:

```
<graph string="Sales Repersentative/Team performance" type="pie">
```

nevertheless this tag has no effects a part of my code is:

```
<record id="graph_mia_sale_representative_team_performance" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">graph.sale.representative.team.performance</field>
<field name="model">reporting.sale.representative.team.performance</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <graph string="Sales Repersentative/Team performance" type="pie">
        <field 
            name="calendar_month_name_year" 
            type="row" />
        <field 
            name="revenue"
            type="measure" />
    </graph>
</field>
```

I have no error in my code, using the graph type buttons i can perfectly change the type of graph with no error

Am i missing something or odoo documentation isn't complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the graph_mode value in context with the associated action to the graph view, for example

```
<field name="context">
    { 'graph_mode': 'pie' }
</field>
```